# Dataframe Split and transpose such that the leftmost value becomes the header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe column with pairs of data, LHS is the column name, RHS is the column value:

```
display(df_Normal.head(1))

Data
0  {'MktUMidInit': 'a', 'ProdTemplateName': '', 'ForwardPriceDrop': '99.10', 'CoverPrice': '99.20 'CustParentCdr': '', ...}
```

Desired output:

```
Data
MktUMidInit ProdTemplateName ForwardPriceDrop CoverPrice CustParentCdr...
a                            99.10            99.20
```

There are over fifty pairs of data in each row

```
df.head(1).to_dict() 

{'Data': {0: {'Action': 'CustAcceptedQuote',
   'AllQ': '104.643',
   'AutoNegDealerMidValue': '0',
   'AutoNegDealerSpread': '0',
   'AutoNegDealerValue': '-1',
   'ClearingChannel': '',
   'ClearingCode': '',
   'ClearingHouse': '',
   'ClearingMember': '',
   'ClearingModel': '',
   'CneResultMessage': '',
   'Code': 'AU3TB0000036',
   'Commission': '', }}}
```

I was thinking of first splitting on the comma then trasposing. The split command appears not to work on the data:

```
dfSplit = df_Normal['Data'].str.split(',', 1, expand=True)
display(dfSplit.head(1))

NaN
```

For the traspose I looks at df.set_index but this errored. and Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you print `df.head(5).to_dict()` and pasted it in your question as text?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have JSON data that you want to *normalize* into a DataFrame. There's a function to do that:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
json_normalize(df.Data.tolist())
```

Alternatively, you may use `pd.DataFrame.from_records`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.Data.tolist())
```

```
              Action     AllQ AutoNegDealerMidValue AutoNegDealerSpread  \
0  CustAcceptedQuote  104.643                     0                   0   

  AutoNegDealerValue ClearingChannel ClearingCode ClearingHouse  \
0                 -1                                              

  ClearingMember ClearingModel CneResultMessage          Code Commission  
0                                                AU3TB0000036
```

Comment: Yes @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ a JSON file from pymongo. Thanks,m works well!!